# curl works to get PDF, but JavaScript fetch does not

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have a specific API I call to get a PDF, and it works perfectly with curl:

```
curl --location --request GET "https://app.hiddensite.com/api/v2/dn/jobs/export/INV-00181?format=pdf&document=pod&type=Delivery" --header "x-api-key: cfe5750a5d5114xxxxxxxxxxxx49dabb3e98c0cc63424cb014f" > a.pdf
```

However, when I call like this:

```
const r = await fetch('https://app.hiddensite.com/api/v2/dn/jobs/export/INV-00181?format=pdf&document=pod&type=Delivery',
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': 'cfe5750a5d5114xxxxxxxxxxxx49dabb3e98c0cc63424cb014f',
        },
    });
return r.text()
```

I get a slightly differently sized PDF that almost displays correctly, but the graphics are gone and it's only the text - i.e. it is slightly malformed somehow. I get this whether trying fs.writeFileSync() or just console.logging the output and piping to file.

Any idea what could cause these to be slightly different?

Comment: `text` resolves with a string. I think what you want is `blob`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFs are not entirely text files, so trying to read it as one with `.text()` is introducing errors into the binary parts of it (e.g. the graphics!).

You need `r.blob()`.